# backup util for binary/media files. (to use with source control)

Tags: windows-7, backup, source-control

I am using git for my source control. I dont backup media such as gifs, pngs, etc. I am thinking everytime i tag a release it would be a good idea to backup the media files as well. But i dont want to make several copies of the same file each time i create a tag. I'd like an app to handle checking if the file already exists and handles restoring everything to a version i like

What util might i use to do this?

I'm using windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

[rdiff-backup](http://www.nongnu.org/rdiff-backup/) - It is a simple perl script using rsync (copies only modified files). Can backup local to local directories, local to remote, remote to local or remote to remote, Can tunnel through ssh for security.

The best feature is it keeps file versions and you can restore files not only to the last version, but previous as well, saves only diffs - less network traffic.

It is easy to schedule it in cronjob in Linux, probably works under Windows as well.

Comment: As a highly valued Super User, I suggest you revisit this answer and [add more detail](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5177/what-do-we-do-with-low-quality-answers-from-high-rep-users), for example how a screen shot or a brief overview of how the software works?